# How to find more than one element in focus

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML where more that one element is active.

```
`document.activeElement `
```

returns the first one, but I need to find the second element which is in focus.

sample code as follows.

```
`<ul Class="ul1" Active="true">
   <!-- some tags-->
       <ul class="ul2">
           <li Active="true">My Element</li>
       </ul>            
   </ul>`
```

I need to find My Element in the above code which is dynamic(Some tags part will have different combination of tags), also position of li in UL2 will vary.

Please help to get the second element with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('[Active="true"] [Active="true"]')
```

this will select every active child of every active element. Sadly, though it will also select the 3rd, 4th... nth child.
So if you have any other way to differentiate which one is the 2nd one, then the task will be much simpler.
If it makes any difference - the very fist element in the returned array will be what you need. but If you have several "2nd active children" you want to select - then you'll have no luck.

also:

```
document.querySelector('[Active="true"] [Active="true"]')
```

will return the first match, which is an active child of an active element.

Comment: if it worked for you, please hit the upvote or "best answer"

Comment: you must be eligible to choose the best answer of your own questions :)